# How to convert a table to a list with row & column header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Is there formala in excel or google spreed sheet can convert a table to a list like this?

from this table:

[image: Table]

to this list:

[image: List]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may ***try*** any one of the following approaches, as per your **Excel version**.

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• If you are using **Excel 2010/2013/2016/2019/2021/MS365**, then this one works for all

Formula used in cell `A6`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,INT((ROW()-6)/COLUMNS($B$1:$D$1))+1)
```

Formula used in cell `B6`

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD((ROW()-6),ROWS($A$2:$A$4))+1)
```

Formula used in cell `C6`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(A6,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(B6,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

**Note:** You may need to change the `(ROW()-6)` depending on the `ROW()` from where you are entering the formula for transformation. Example, like if you start from cell or row 3 then it will be `(ROW()-3)` so on so forth accordingly as per your suit.

---

• If you are using **MS365** and when writing if you have enabled the **Office Insiders Beta Channel Version** then, using `LAMBDA()` `HSTACK()` `TEXTSPLIT()` `DROP()` `TAKE()` `TOCOL()` & `TEXTJOIN()` can achieve it as well.

```
=LAMBDA(array,
HSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(".",1,
DROP(TAKE(array,,1)&"-"&TAKE(array,1),1,1)),"-","."),
TOCOL(DROP(array,1,1))))(A1:D4)
```

---

• **Also Note** : You can use a ***custom***, ***reusable*** formula with a ***friendly name*** by placing the above formula in the **Name Manager** - with **Define Name** as `UNPIVOT`.

So from **Formulas** tab, Click on **Define Name** --> Enter the name as **UNPIVOT** and place the above formula as in **refers to**

```
=LAMBDA(array,
HSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(".",1,
DROP(TAKE(array,,1)&"-"&TAKE(array,1),1,1)),"-","."),
TOCOL(DROP(array,1,1))))
```

The syntax is

```
=UNPIVOT(array)
```

Where array is `A1:D4`

---

**Closing Note:** You can also achieve the above transformation using **Power Query** as well.

Comment: Just perfect. All three suggestions work perfectly. I wish I could mark it as solution myself. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: @ikso glad to know that it worked for you =)